# ngFor creating elements from json Array

Tags: arrays, json, ngfor

I have array from json data and structure is like this:

```
connectionPoints:Array(2)
0:
 id:"717cd12b-6ab3-49cf-ac7e-0a2b8db34715"
 position:{x: 1.1094055, y: -1.6641006, z: 0}
 system:null
 type:"Link1"

1:
 id:"23de5r51-6ab3-49cf-ac7e-0a2b8db34715"
 position:{x: 1.2314055, y: -1.1141006, z: 0}
 system:null
 type:"Link2"
```

I created table from divs and input in html to show data:

```
<div class="Table">
    <div class="Table-header">
        <div class="xyz-style">X</div>
        <div class="xyz-style">Y</div>
        <div class="xyz-style">Z</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Table-row ">    
        <input type="text" value={{conPoint.position.x}}/>
        <input type="text" value={{conPoint.position.y}}/>
        <input type="text" value={{conPoint.position.z}}/>
    </div>
    <div class="flex50v2">
        <label class="label-prop">Type</label>
        <div style="width:50%">
        <input class="input-prop" type="text" value={{conPoint.type}}/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex50v2">
        <label class="label-prop">System</label>
        <div style="width:50%">
        <input class="input-prop" type="text" value={{conPoint.system}}/>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

conPoint is getting data array like in first code.

My question is how can I generate complete table for each connection point in this array, and to get x,y,z positions for every one of that connection points created.

I know that if I get ngFor in table it will generate it that many times in array, but i have problem cause I get error on x,y,z ...Is there any fix or corrections in code? Thanks

Comment: What did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: @Andy i tried to set *ngFor="let co of conPoint" in top Table div. It did generated fields ok, but had TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined and it keeps multiplying over and over.

Comment: So the loop-variable is _co_. Try ``{{co.position.x}}, {{co.position.y}}`` etc then.

Comment: Thanks, thats it ...i totally forgot that I have to set it to singe element, not complete array !!! Thanks again